# Where is the options menu for Convert mesh to Grease Pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil, conversion

I dont understand how to find the options menu for Convert to Grease Pencil.

---

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/convert.html?highlight=convert%20grease

Object ‣ Convert to ‣ Grease Pencil from Curve/Mesh

Converts the selected curve or mesh object to a Grease Pencil object with strokes matching the curve/mesh; basic materials are also add. When multiple curves/meshes are selected, they are all converted into the same Grease Pencil object.

Options
Keep Original
Duplicates the original object before converting it.

Thickness
Strokes thickness.

Threshold Angle
Threshold value that determines the strokes end.

Stroke Offset
Sets offset to separate strokes from filled strokes.

Only Seam Edges
Convert only edges marked as seam.

Export Faces
Convert faces as filled strokes.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you know the first step, which is how to convert to grease pencil, but not how to access the options.

[image: Convert]

To get the options you listed, look for a little box in the bottom corner that says "Convert to" after you perform the convert operation (it may be collapsed at first - just click on it to open and access the options)

[image: ConvertOptions]